# CUDA Nsight - save informations about a kernel execution to an excel file

Tags: c++, cuda, nsight

Is there any way to save the profiling of a kernel in some kind of spreadsheet file? That would help me greatly to have average values for my kernel execution times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [nvprof command line profiler](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#nvprof-overview)  has a [CSV output option](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#csv) which can be used to save kernel execution statistics.

The legacy [command line profiler](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#compute-command-line-profiler-overview) also has a CSV output option.

These CSV files can also [later be imported](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#sessions) into the visual profiler.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to Nsight Visual Studio Edition, you can export to a number of file formats.  See the [Nsight Visual Studio User guide Analysis Reports chapter](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/3.0/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Nsight_Visual_Studio_Edition_User_Guide.htm#Analysis_Reports.htm)